# SoX how do I make mixing not decrease the volume

Tags: sox

When I mix four tracks, the sound decreases by a lot, I've tried mix-volume and mix.
How do I make it so the volume doesnt change?

I tried `-M after "sox --combine mix-power"`, but the end file was 0 seconds long.

Answer (score 11):

just add -v 1 before each input file - like this: -v 1 file.wav

Answer (score 4):

> How do I make it so the volume doesnt change?

### Short answer

You can't, you can only get estimated similarity. The estimation could come from adjusting gain while listening to the final result or perhaps adjusting gain based on the RMS level of the output.

If you are lucky [*@Yuki's* answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23410018/1331399) might not result in any clipping and give you a reasonable result.

### Longer answer

When you mix the tracks, they are essentially added to each other. This means it is easy to exceed the maximum value a sample can have and thus result in clipping. To avoid this problem `sox` divides each track with the total number of tracks before adding

Assuming you have 4 files called `1.wav`, `2.wav`, `3.wav` and `4.wav`, here  are a couple of simple ways of achieving a reasonable result (depending on your situation):

**Normalize each file before mixing**

```
sox --combine mix "|sox 1.wav -p gain -n" \
                  "|sox 2.wav -p gain -n" \
                  "|sox 3.wav -p gain -n" \
                  "|sox 4.wav -p gain -n" \
                  out.wav
```

**Normalize the final result**

```
sox --combine mix 1.wav 2.wav 3.wav 4.wav out.wav gain -n
```

**Add gain to the final result**

```
sox --combine mix 1.wav 2.wav 3.wav 4.wav out.wav
```

Now add gain with the `gain` effect, besides the normalize-flag (`-n`) it also accepts dB values, e.g. to add 6 dB gain:

```
sox out.wav out-with-gain.wav gain +6
```

You can listen to the result either with `play(1)` or by setting the output file to `-d`, e.g.:

```
play out.wav gain +6
```

or:

```
sox out.wav -d gain +6
```

Comment: Gain -n normalizes. This is not what the question was about. And this further adds confusion because you refer to "n" as the number of input files. If people substitute n with their number of input files they will just reduce the volume even more.

Comment: @Albin: After reading the question and my answer again, I can see what you mean. I have tried to remove the confusion and added some alternative ways of dealing with file mixing and volume adjustment.

Comment: This is so much better! Maybe `gain -l +6` though? `-l` applies a limiter to avoid clipping. I used to think gain implicitly did this, but it seems not according to the manual. Or did I read it wrong?

Comment: @Albin: depending on how much clipping is going on `-l` may cause unwanted distortions, so I would be careful to recommend it as a general solution.